# how to display the another view ,after destroyed the one view using sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

My main  view containing the following code

```
items: [
            {
                xtype:'headerpage',
                docked:'top'
            },
            {  // this is the content area...
                id: 'launchscreen',
                cls : 'card',
                scrollable: true,
               xtype:'informationpage'
            },
            {
                docked:'left',
                xtype:'page1',
                store: 'page1'
            }

        ],
```

In store i have 2 buttons page1,page2.

when i click the page2 button it should display page2 view ,i tried the following

```
 control: {
       '#page2id':{
                tap:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('launchscreen').destroy();
                    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('App.view.page2'));
                   // Ext.Viewport.add('App.view.Page2');
                }
            }
}
```

by using the above launchscreen is destroyed,but page2 isn't displayed in the place of lauchscreen.can anyone help me ...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to the container where the launchscreen is placed in:

```
id: 'mainContainer',
items: [
            {
                xtype:'headerpage',
                docked:'top'
            },
            {  // this is the content area...
                id: 'launchscreen',
                cls : 'card',
                scrollable: true,
               xtype:'informationpage'
            },
            {
                docked:'left',
                xtype:'page1',
                store: 'page1'
            }

        ],
```

Then you can add the second page  to your container:

Controller Code:

```
 control: {
           '#page2id':{
                    tap:function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('launchscreen').destroy();
                        var page2 = Ext.getCmp('mainContainer').add(Ext.create('App.view.page2'));
                        Ext.getCmp('mainContainer').setActiveItem(page2); 
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Lukas K,now ,im getting another problem.when i click the page2 button,it displays page2 view.after that i clicked page1 button,it doesn't open the page1 view.and another intresting thing is ,after reloaded the application if i click page1 ,it displayed page1 view,then i clicked the page2 button but it's not working.can you help me to solve this...

Comment: Can you post your code of the views and your controller in http://www.senchafiddle.com/ ?

Comment: I fixed it http://www.senchafiddle.com/#hTBUR#wLAkE. First i changed your id of the second page to "page2id", because "page2" was still at another point. Then i changed the functions in your controller. The problem in the controller was, that at the second click the launchscreen was still destroyed and the javascript stopped for that reason

Answer (score 0):

Currently you just added new view into the `viewport`, you also need to use [setActiveItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-method-setActiveItem) to display your `page2` view:

```
Ext.getCmp('launchscreen').destroy();
var page2 = Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('App.view.page2'));
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(page2);
```

Or you can use [animateActiveItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-method-animateActiveItem) to animate your `viewport` with specified animation, for example:

```
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(page2, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
```

Comment: user1479606,thanks for the answer,  yes,now it displays the view in the new screen,when i click the button page2 .but it should display page2 in the same place of launchscreen.